# Cross compilation of OpenCV for ARM based Linux system

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, linker, gdbserver

I tried to setup my cross compilation toolchain to compile applications that use OpenCV for an ARM board on my Ubuntu host system. 
What I did is compile OpenCV with this command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake ../../..
```

After that I used make and make install to finish the build of OpenCV.

I then told eclipse where the include directories of my freshly OpenCV build are and told the linker where the libraries could be found. The build process of the application works fine and the application is built.

In the next step I tried remote debug my application via gdb but it terminated with this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Do I have to put the compiled libraries onto the target system? If so where should I put them? I thought that because of the compilation process happening on the host system the libraries wouldn't be needed on the target system anymore. Is that wrong?

Comment: All executables, and executable code, need to reside on the target platform.  As to *where* to put them, it depends.  For development, the general destination is memory (a.k.a. SRAM, DDR).  For release maybe in Read-Only Memory (Flash, EEPROM, ROM, etc.).